# Rails CSV.Parse giving Errno::EISDIR - when the parsed string contains directory names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in an index.html.erb:

```
<% CSV.parse(thetest.tags) do |row| %>
   <% row.each do |a| %> 
      <div class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><%= a %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which gives me the following error, only when 'thetest.tags' contains a string called 'test', as it is a directory.

```
Errno::EISDIR in Tests#index
Is a directory - test
Extracted source (around line #9):
```

Is there something wrong with the ruby code, or would this be a problem with my routes.rb?

Edit 1:
Any other values in this string 'tags' work, eg 'abc,apple,123'. It only errors if it includes test, eg 'test,any,other,value'. Disregard anything by padde, he is useless.

Comment: Why the f*** would you want to parse csv in a view?

Comment: @padde: Probably because the tags are being stored in a single column in CSV format.

Comment: @muistooshort of course, this is what the code intends to do. I am not saying parsing CSV is bad, i'm just saying the view is the wrong place to do it.

Comment: @padde: I'd go another step and say that storing CSV in a column is a bad idea period. But even so, swearing at someone in public isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: What does the offending `thetest.tags` value look like? There must be something else going on, I can `CSV.parse` when the CSV matches a directory name without any problems. Can you include the full error message?

Comment: @muistooshort you're right i wasn't being helpful and a bit rude. I hereby apologize for that. As you already said, no proper answer can be given without additional information, i.e. what `thetest.tags` contains. @Tallisado said it would contain `'test'` but that cannot be true, because then the code runs without problems. I am guessing a file is being read in the background and this file happens to be a directory and thus cannot be read from.

Comment: thetest.tags provides the above error when it contains the word 'test' in the csv string. The question contains the entire exception that was thrown.